# Solutions to Biler and Witkowski

Tags: analysis

I am currently working through Biler and Witkowski's book, Problems in Mathematical Analysis - which I have found to be one of the greatest problem book in analysis that I've ever opened. I was wondering if anyone could point my in the right direction as to where I could find a solutions manual to the text.

Comment: There are answers at the end of the book, although concise.